# Neural network weight matrix algebra for non-standard networks

Tags: linear-algebra, neural-networks

Many neural networks(or multi-layer perceptron) are set up with weight matrices $W_1...W_n$ where $n$ is the number of layers minus one. Each weight matrix $W_k$ represents the connection weights between layer $k$ and $k+1$ is my understanding(may not be wholly correct but gets the idea across).

My question is can the weights for a non-standard network where neurons in layer $k$ can connect to any other non-input layers be represented in a matrix or series of matrices?

Comment: a general neural network is $y_j = f_j(\sum_i W_{i,j} y_i)$, or $y_j(t+1) = f_j(\sum_i W_{i,j} y_i(t))$ when there are cycles in the network so that the activations are time-dependent, and in matrix vector notation : $y(t+1) = f(W^T \times y(t))$

Comment: Is that a yes to my question or a correction to my post?

Comment: yes. in a general neural network there is a graph of neurons, possibly with cycles, and there are no layers constraining the connections. You should forget about the layers and prove the back-propagation algorithm by considering a general cycles-free neural network.

Comment: Yeah, I realized I could simulate a connection bypassing a layer by adding a "ghost" neuron to the bypassed layer, with the corresponding weights all set to 1 and not modified by the backpropagation algorithm - probably with a mask.

Comment: I don't quite have enough math to do what you suggest though. Graduated school some time ago, so exploring these topics on my own time and interest. But thank you!